# Binary Tree Recursion Parameter not updated

Tags: python, recursion, scope, binary-tree

I am trying to write a function returns the sum of all of a binary tree's subtrees' nodes' depths.
Here is my first attempt, I try to store the sum of depths in "sumOfDepths" and pass it during recursions:

```
def allKindsOfNodeDepths(root):
    return getSumOfDepths(root, 0, 0)

def getSumOfDepths(node, sumOfDepths, depth):
    if node is None:
        return sumOfDepths
    sumOfDepths += depth * (depth + 1) / 2
    getSumOfDepths(node.left, sumOfDepths, depth + 1)
    getSumOfDepths(node.right, sumOfDepths, depth + 1)
    return sumOfDepths


# This is the class of the input binary tree.
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

However, I got 0 rather than the correct sum.

Then I try to store it in a list then pass it down:

```
def allKindsOfNodeDepths(root):
    return getSumOfDepths(root, [], 0)

def getSumOfDepths(node, depthsList, depth):
    if node is None:
        return
    depthsList.append(depth * (depth + 1) / 2)
    getSumOfDepths(node.left, depthsList, depth + 1)
    getSumOfDepths(node.right, depthsList, depth + 1)
    return sum(depthsList)


# This is the class of the input binary tree.
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Just wonder why the first one did not work but the second one goes through?
I guess it is because of the scope of the function, and the immutable feature of the list...
But still cannot come up with a clear idea about it.

Comment: Variables are passed by value, not reference. Assigning to the parameter variable doesn't  modify the caller's variable.

Comment: The second one passes a reference to a mutable object and modifies its contents.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, do you mean getSumOfDepths(root, 0, 0) is the caller, when it calls getSumOfDepths(root.left, 0, 1), caller's parameter sumOfDepths will not change since it has not been passed by value?

Comment: There is no `sumOfDepths` variable in the caller there. I was talking about `getSumOfDepths(node.left, sumOfDepths, depth + 1)`. The assignment to `sumOfDepths` in the recursive call doesn't affect the caller's variable, because it's passed by value.